# Pyro CMS RESTful API using API_Controller

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I am nob to Pyro CMS and I am trying to create a RESTful API using API_Controller, but when I try to access it, it replies `{"status":false,"error":"This API is currently disabled."}`
how can i get it fixed.. :(

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Api extends API_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
}

public function index_get()
{
$this->response( array('test index' => 'My test'), 200 );
exit;
}

public function test_get($arg1 = NULL)
{
$data = array('test' => 'My test');

if (!empty($arg1))
$data['arg1'] = $arg1;

$this->response( $data, 200 );
exit;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the API access in the PyroCMS backend.

1. Login to your backend
2. Go to "Data \ API Management"
3. Enable the API in the "Overview" section. Click the button on the top right part of the page. The API status should show "Enabled".

Comment: But I dont have API Management option in Data or backend menus anywhere...
:(

Comment: Do you have a PyroCMS Professional Edition, or only the Community Edition? The REST API Module is only available in the Pro Edition.

You might also need to install the API Module first (Backend -> Addons -> Modules, click "install" on the API module)